# javax.imageio.IIOException: Not a JPEG stream (starts with: 0x0003, expected SOI: 0xffd8)

Tags: java, jdbc, javax.imageio

Having problem with converting inputStream to bufferImage.  BufferedImage crfPersonImg is always null and Exception occur at line *Raster raster = reader1.readRaster(0, null);*. This is my code so far

```
//code for getting ByteArray From Blob column in Oracle DB.
    List<Object[]> userRoleList = commonDao.findByNativeSQL(selectSQL
            , new Object[] {examCd, examPeriod, fromMemNo, toMemNo});
    for(Object[] row : userRoleList){
        CertificateDtlsVO cdObj = new CertificateDtlsVO();          
        cdObj.setExmCd(Integer.parseInt(row[0].toString()));
        cdObj.setExmDsc(row[1].toString());
        cdObj.setMemNo(row[2].toString());
        cdObj.setMemNm(row[3].toString());
        cdObj.setCertNo(row[4].toString());
        cdObj.setCertDt(row[5].toString());
        cdObj.setPrtNo(row[6].toString());
        cdObj.setSylCd(row[7].toString());
        cdObj.setNumOfTime(Integer.parseInt(row[8].toString()));
        cdObj.setMemType(row[9].toString());
        cdObj.setClassGrade(row[10].toString());

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(row[11]);           
        cdObj.setPhoto(baos.toByteArray());
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(row[12]);
        cdObj.setSign(baos.toByteArray());
        cdObj.setPhotoBuffImg(ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())));
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        memCertfDtlsList.add(cdObj);
    }
```

//code For converting Byte Array to BufferImage

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(photo);       
    Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("JPEG");
    ImageReader reader1 = null;
    while (readers.hasNext()) {
        reader1 = readers.next();
        if (reader1.canReadRaster()) {
            break;
        }
    }

    //Stream the image file
    ImageInputStream input =   ImageIO.createImageInputStream(in); 
    reader1.setInput(input); 

    //Read the image raster
    Raster raster = reader1.readRaster(0, null); 

    //Create a new RGB image
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(raster.getWidth(), raster.getHeight(), 
            BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR); 

    //Fill the new image with the old raster
    bi.getRaster().setRect(raster);

    BufferedImage crfPersonImg = ImageIO.read(in);
```

> javax.imageio.IIOException: Not a JPEG stream (starts with: 0x0003, expected SOI: 0xffd8)
>       at com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGSegmentImageInputStream.streamInit(JPEGSegmentImageInputStream.java:247)
>       at com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGSegmentImageInputStream.fetchSegment(JPEGSegmentImageInputStream.java:71)
>       at com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGSegmentImageInputStream.repositionAsNecessary(JPEGSegmentImageInputStream.java:267)

Sample Image [image: sample Image]

Comment: I tried to read your file directly using both `ImageIO.read()` and `ImageReader.readRaster()`, and it worked fine in both cases. I don't understand why you need both, but they work. So, I would suspect that the problem is in the code you don't show. Like, what is `photo`? A `byte` array? How is it filled?

Comment: **InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(photo)** line I am using for converting photo byte[] to inputStream. [Here is my second sample of Image](http://fotoforensics.com/analysis.php?id=70c5fd394b5e086bdc9b74db7944cc6c222c7818.8021&fmt=orig)

Comment: @haraldK **InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(photo)** line I am using for converting photo byte[] to inputStream. [Here is my second sample of Image](http://fotoforensics.com/analysis.php?id=70c5fd394b5e086bdc9b74db7944cc6c222c7818.8021&fmt=orig) and [Byte Array](https://ufile.io/7iqst). I filled by dataBase oracle Blob column. Its jpeg fomate.

Comment: @haraldK, I have updated my Code. Please have a look.

Comment: Looking at your byte array values, I can tell that definitively isn't a JPEG file..

Comment: @haraldK, The file  Provided you is directly downloaded from DB tool : Oracle sql developer.

Comment: Okay, I seem to have found the issue... Your "byte array" seems to be serialized-representation of the blob, rather than the data in the blob... Decoding it as a UTF8-string, it starts with `"java.sql.Blob %org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.WrappedBlob"`... Sounds familiar? :-)

Comment: @haraldK, yea, I just found out i need to get it by java.sql.Blob as you said during chat "fetch method was not correct".  Again, Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @haraldK, Solved my Issue by changing code of getting byte array from blob column.

```
List<Object[]> userRoleList = commonDao.findByNativeSQL(selectSQL
            , new Object[] {examCd, examPeriod, fromMemNo, toMemNo});
    for(Object[] row : userRoleList){
        CertificateDtlsVO cdObj = new CertificateDtlsVO();          
        cdObj.setExmCd(Integer.parseInt(row[0].toString()));
        cdObj.setExmDsc(row[1].toString());
        cdObj.setMemNo(row[2].toString());
        cdObj.setMemNm(row[3].toString());
        cdObj.setCertNo(row[4].toString());
        cdObj.setCertDt(row[5].toString());
        cdObj.setPrtNo(row[6].toString());
        cdObj.setSylCd(row[7].toString());
        cdObj.setNumOfTime(Integer.parseInt(row[8].toString()));
        cdObj.setMemType(row[9].toString());
        cdObj.setClassGrade(row[10].toString());
        InputStream photoBlob = ((Blob) row[11]).getBinaryStream();
        InputStream signBlob = ((Blob) row[12]).getBinaryStream();
        cdObj.setPhoto(IOUtils.toByteArray(photoBlob));
        cdObj.setSign(IOUtils.toByteArray(signBlob));
        memCertfDtlsList.add(cdObj);
    }
```